# How to reverse the all element of ArrayList using reverse method?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have to make a method that can reverse all elements of ArrayList ...
For exmaple,
if my list have <12 1 34 56 43> elements. then it should reverse the whole list.
<43 56 34 1 12>.
I've tried this method, but it doesn't work. Here is the method

```
public void reverse() { 
int size=0;     
for (int i = 0, j = size - 1; i < size && j >= 0; i++, j--)     
{         
int temp = j;         
j = i;         
i = temp;         
}          
}
```

when I call this method list.revese(). it doesn't reverse the list.
Can anyone please help me out!!!

Comment: Your method is not accessing any elements of the underlying list, only manipulating the indices. You need to use the [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) and [`set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#set%28int,%20E%29) methods in order to actually modify the list.

Comment: @MickMnemonic seriously should be an answer...

Answer (score 3):

Your code deals with the index but not the actual element of the index. Also note that if j < i, you are doing the reversing twice, thus there will be no effect.

```
public void reverse(List<Integer> list) { 
  int size=list.size();     
  for (int i = 0, j = size - 1; i < size && j >= 0 && i <= j; /** i must be smaller. */ i++, j--)     
  {         
    int temp = list.get(j);         
    list.set(j, list.get(i));         
    list.set(i,temp);         
  }          
}
```

Comment: I tried this using .get but actually I've to put this method in LList.java. which contains all method like append, remove, length, etc. but it doesn't contain the .get method so i got error "can not find the symbol"!!!! is there any other way to do this without using .get() method??

Comment: What is the `LList` class? Is it a customized class that you can modify the source code? In that case you need to get the element in that list (e.g. in an array).

Comment: yes it is a customized class that can modify the source code.>

Comment: In that case if it is an array, you can replace the `list.get(i)` with something like `arr[i]`.

Comment: hmm but `<1,2,3,4,5>` is not valid java code? Sorry I don't understand

Answer (score 2):

Use the ArrayList object, and then after building your array you can just run the following to reverse the contents:

```
Collections.reverse(your ArrayList Here);
```

Comment: Oh, then I will make the correct snippet for you, give me one second.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize 'size' variable to the length of the ArrayList. You are initializing it to 0.